# Proof about members of resolvent set of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the operator $T: \mathcal{C}([0,1])\to \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ (with the sup norm) defined by $Tf(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$. I found the resolvent of this operator to be:
$$(T-\lambda)^{-1}g=\frac{-1}{\lambda^2}\int_0^xe^{(x-t)/\lambda}g(t)dt-\frac{1}{\lambda}g(x)$$.
I want to show that any non-zero $\lambda$ belongs to the resolvent set of $T$. Intuitively, it seems clear that the resolvent is bounded for any $\lambda\neq 0$. I tried to prove this by naively taking the norm $||(T-\lambda)^{-1}g||$ and tried to show that $||(T-\lambda)^{-1}g||\leq K||g||$ for some $K$. I will leave the $\frac{-1}{\lambda}g(x)$ term out of consideration because it's trivial. I got
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\frac{-1}{\lambda^2}\int_0^xe^{(x-t)/\lambda}g(t)dt|\leq \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}e^{x/\lambda}\int_0^x|e^{-t/\lambda}g(t)|dt=\frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}e^{1/\lambda}\int_0^1e^{-t/\lambda}|g(t)|dt$$
Here I got stuck, because I would want to apply something like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I don't know of anything that could be applied here. One thought that occurred to me would be to say that $e^{-t/\lambda}$ is a decreasing function, thus maximal at $0$ on the interval $[0,1]$, and hence $\int_0^1e^{-t/\lambda}|g(t)|dt\leq \int_0^1e^0|g(t)|dt\leq||g||$. However, after my failed earlier attempt, this seemed too suspiciously easy. I would appreciate some sort of verification and/or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
    |((T-\lambda I)^{-1}g)(x)| \le \frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)\Re\lambda/|\lambda|^2}|g(t)|dt+\frac{1}{|\lambda|}|g(x)| \\
  \le \left(\frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}\int_0^xe^{(x-t)\Re\lambda/|\lambda|^2}dt+\frac{1}{|\lambda|}\right)\|g\|
$$
I'll leave it to you to find an absolute bound in $x\in [0,1]$ for a fixed $\lambda\ne 0$, and to conclude that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded for $\lambda\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I got it from there. I still ended up using the fact that (after evaluating the integral), I have an increasing function of $x$, which means that the supremum over all $x\in[0,1]$ is attained at the boundary $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: @QuaereVerum : That looks correct. The integral is straightforward.